# multiple calculation in window function

Tags: scala, apache-spark

In spark, I am trying to calculate three transactions in same window. As I have another example using the same windows many times, it takes too much time. I shortened my example as below. Is it possible to do this in one window function like below. It is throwing error as expected...

```
val sonuc = data.withColumn("meanError",
  struct(mean($"errorGeneral"),min($"errorGeneral")).over(
  Window.partitionBy($"id").orderBy($"time".asc).rangeBetween(-240*3600,
  0)))
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with:

```
val w = Window.partitionBy($"id").orderBy($"time".asc).rangeBetween(-240*3600, 0)

data.select($"*"
  mean($"errorGeneral").over(w),
  min($"errorGeneral").over(w)
)
```

Internally Spark will have to shuffle and order only once.

If this is slow, it is because window functions are on the top of the most expensive operations in Spark, especially with wide frames like this one.